# the underlying compression routine could not reserve sufficient memory

Tags: c#, compression, gzip

I am trying to process messages from the service bus queue. So basically my handler unzips the message and process. The below code is meant to unzip but i seeing a lot of messages sitting in the dead letter queue and the error message is "the underlying compression routine could not reserve sufficient memory". Appreciate if you could please comment on the code below? App insights failures are pointing me to the Unzip method below.

```
public static class StringCompression
{
    public static void CopyTo(Stream src, Stream dest)
    {
        var bytes = new byte[4096];

        int cnt;

        while ((cnt = src.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
        {
            dest.Write(bytes, 0, cnt);
        }
    }

    public static string Unzip(byte[] bytes)
    {
        using (var msi = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        using (var mso = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var gs = new GZipStream(msi, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                //gs.CopyTo(mso);
                CopyTo(gs, mso);
            }

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mso.ToArray());
        }
    }

    public static byte[] Zip(string str)
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);

        using (var msi = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        using (var mso = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var gs = new GZipStream(mso, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                //msi.CopyTo(gs);
                CopyTo(msi, gs);
            }

            return mso.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside, why are you using your own `CopyTo` method rather than using the built-in `Stream.CopyTo`?

Comment: Provided that your strings aren't too large, there's nothing obviously wrong with that code. The error message suggests that your server is running out of memory however: have you checked that?

Comment: (If your strings are large, there are many things you could do to reduce the memory usage of your code... But you'll still be stuck allocating lots of large strings)

Comment: Thanks canton7 - the handler sits as an azure function so if the server was running out of memory surely the portal would have notified? Appreciate our thoughts as my knowledge isn't great on the infrastructure side of Paas.

Comment: Maybe it's exceeding the memory it's allowed to use? I'm not familiar with Azure's PAAS, but the error message is clear

Comment: Are you running 32-bit code? That may reduce the maximum memory size that can be allocated. Another possibility is a memory leak somewhere else, that eventually consumes all the memory, and causes a crash where the largest blocks are allocated, not where the memory is leaked. I would recommend some memory profiling.

Comment: @JonasH Both very unlikely in an azure function...?

Comment: @canton7 I'm just guessing, and you might be right. Its not obvious to me if azure functions are spawning a new process for each call or not, the documentation is somewhat ambigous. Still, doing some memory profiling, even if just by logging, might be useful to see if the memory usage is higher than expected.

Comment: Might just be a bug in .NET. (There have been many in their compression code.) What version are you using? Can you try a more recent version?

Comment: Thanks Mark - The library is in .NET Standard 2.0, so pretty latest